# AWS Amplify Signup InvalidParameterException: Attributes did not conform

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito

I have a react native application and I am trying to integrate AWS amplify to my project. Right now, I have collected all of the required infomraiton that I need to create an account. I have everything saves in state. WHen I try to actually signup and create an account, I run into an issue I have tried several time to fux but nothing seems to be working.

Here is my sugnupUser function:

```
import { signUp } from 'aws-amplify/auth'

const signupUser = () => {
    signUp({
      username: username, 
      password: password,
      attributes: {
        username: username, 
        email: email, 
        preferred_username: username,
        phone_number: `+1${phone}`, 
        'custom:following': 0,
        'custom:followers': 0,
        'custom:favorites': 0
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('new user')
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error: ', error)
      })
  }
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
 LOG  error:  [InvalidParameterException: Attributes did not conform to the schema: name: The attribute is required
preferred_username: The attribute is required
email: The attribute is required
phone_number: The attribute is required
```

Here is the stored information in useState:

```
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [verify, setVerify] = useState('')
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('')
  const [location, setLocation] = useState('')
```

Not sure why I keep getting this error or how to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says you need to put your user attributes in an `options` object:

```js
import { signUp } from 'aws-amplify/auth';

async function handleSignUp() {
  try {
    await signUp({
      username: 'jdoe',
      password: 'mysecurerandompassword#123',
      options: {
        userAttributes: {
          email: 'me@domain.com',
          phone_number: '+12128601234', // E.164 number convention
          given_name: 'Jane',
          family_name: 'Doe',
          nickname: 'Jane'
        }
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/auth/manage-user-profile/